# Cannot print variable in local for terraform after apply project. Terraform print known after apply

Tags: terraform

I try print variable in local for terraform after apply project. Terraform print known after apply. Terraform version is v0.14.5

Main code https://github.com/patsevanton/terraform-yandex-cloud-examples/blob/main/terraform-count/inventory.tf

```
locals {
  name_attribute = "fqdn"
  group_tag = "labels"
  instances = concat(
    yandex_compute_instance.vm_1, yandex_compute_instance.vm_2
  )
 .........
}
```

I run `terraform apply`, terraform created resource.

```
yandex_vpc_network.network-1: Creating...
yandex_vpc_network.network-1: Creation complete after 2s [id=enp6dunid3n9lritpr4j]
yandex_vpc_subnet.subnet-1: Creating...
yandex_vpc_subnet.subnet-1: Creation complete after 0s [id=e9ba67sdgqfkni8n9ks5]
yandex_compute_instance.vm_1[0]: Creating...
yandex_compute_instance.vm_1[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
yandex_compute_instance.vm_1[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
yandex_compute_instance.vm_1[0]: Creation complete after 26s [id=fhmncj5leton3br3nch9]
local_file.inventory: Creating...
local_file.inventory: Creation complete after 0s [id=c7377ed426dbf44a250a9293afd2dc55e6c279c5]

Apply complete! Resources: 4 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

inventory_file = "./inventory.yaml"
```

I run terraform console

```
terraform console
> local.instances
(known after apply)
```

How print variable in local for terraform after apply project ?

Comment: What is your `local.instances`? Do you have any code example to show how it is obtained?

Comment: Your output shows that you are creating only `vm_1`. What about `vm_2` which is present in your `local.instances`?

Comment: You are right! Big Thanks! I dont create vm_2. After create vm_2 local.instances show in terraform console. Please answer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **missing** `vm_2` instance. Once the instance was added, `local.instances` worked as expected in the `terraform console`.